# Why having the ARCH= when we already have CROSS_COMPILE=

Tags: kernel, makefile, kernel-module

This question might be sound obvious to some of you, but to me, it looks like a missing piece that I need in order to understand the picture.

**Edit**: Specifically, I'm using Ubuntu VM on my PC, trying to build an Out-of-Tree kernel module that should run on BeagleBone Black,

In the make command I usually need to enter the following 2 parameters:

1. **ARCH**=
2. **CROSS_COMPILE**=
   To me "1" looks like redundant information that only adds to the complexity of the make command.

Of course, there is a solid reason why using both of them, and I tried to search in many forums and sites, but couldn't find an "answer for dummies" - I guess this is what I'm looking for.

So - my question: Isn't specifying the **CROSS_COMPILE**= enough to build the source code? taking for example:

- **arm**-linux-gnueabihf-
- **aarch64**-none-elf-
- **arm**-none-linux-gnueabihf

In all of the above options, we have the target CPU architecture, which is **arm** or **aarch64** (which is also arm64).

So why do we need a specific directive such as ARCH= if the architecture is already implied in the CROSS_COMPILE= directive?

Comment: `ARCH` is generally used to select the parts of the project that must be built, when this depends on the target architecture. `CROSS_COMPILE` is generally used to select a specific cross-compiler. If you use a custom cross-compiler named, e.g., `ccSuper7`, how could the build system guess that your target architecture is ARM?

Answer (score 2):

CROSS_COMPILE is not enough. Although ARCH may mostly be derived from it,
there is no guarantee that a mechanical extraction rule will work
correctly for all of its future values. There is no requirement
that CROSS_COMPILE should start with ARCH, it is just a convention.

From
[Cross-compiling the kernel](https://hugh712.gitbooks.io/embeddedsystem/content/cross-compiling_the_kernel.html),
see that they are not the same at all:

> The CPU architecture and cross-compiler prefix are defined through the
> ARCH and CROSS_COMPILE variables in the toplevel Makefile.
>
> - **ARCH is the name of the architecture**.
>   It is defined by the name of the subdirectory in arch/ in the kernel sources
>   Example: arm if you
>   want to compile a kernel for the arm architecture.
> - **CROSS_COMPILE is the prefix of the cross compilation tools**
>   Example: arm-linux- if your compiler is arm-linux-gcc